# QBFC , QBXML, Get Amount due on Invoice?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

Using the QBFC SDK, I cant seem to locate anything in the OSR that would give me the amount due on an invoice, as the Quickbooks UI keeps track of it.

The Invoice object in QBFC does not have any applied payment(s) details, not can I find reference to manually inspecting payments. Am I perhaps overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `BalanceRemaining` field which gives you what you're looking for.

```
...
<AppliedAmount >AMTTYPE</AppliedAmount>
<BalanceRemaining >AMTTYPE</BalanceRemaining>
...
```

Code should look something like this:

```
if (InvoiceRet.BalanceRemaining != null)
{
    double BalanceRemaining71 = (double)InvoiceRet.BalanceRemaining.GetValue();
}
```